# How To use any Parameter value for VaryByParam in caching page?

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="Button1" %>
```

I type the above code to vary text of Button but it does not vary the value .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VaryByParam` refers to query string parameters. Not the value of buttons or other controls.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?id=10
http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?id=20
```

Would be cached separately if you set:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="id" %>
```